# Specify another file path for ldap.conf when having multiple instances of apache running in ubuntu

Tags: ldap

Currently I run two instances of apache in my ubuntu thanks to this method :

[multiple-apache2-instances-on-ubuntu](https://someofmylearnings.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/multiple-apache2-instances-on-ubuntu/)

Both instances use ldap, one is configured with `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`.
I would like to configure the second one with another ldap.conf file path.

Do you know, how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According man `ldap.conf` manpage:

```
Additional configuration files can be specified using the LDAPCONF  and
LDAPRC  environment  variables.   LDAPCONF  may be set to the path of a
configuration file.  This path can be absolute or relative to the  cur‐
rent working directory.  The LDAPRC, if defined, should be the basename
of a file in the current working directory or in the user's home direc‐
tory.
```

so you should define different `LDACONF` in the apache2 `envvars`.